# Lining up margins in lists to text below

Tags: lists, margins, resume

Suppose I have a resume made in LaTeX. I want to line up the margin of a specific section (or multiple sections, such that it lines up with the rest of the main text of the page. In particular, I want to line up the text in `Margin1` and `Margin2` below, such that the text in `\itemize` ends before the `\hfill`. Is this possible? Setting up custom margins (in particular, redefining the right margin for a single paragraph/section) seems to only cause the text to shift left, which is undesirable. I want the left margin to stay the same, while changing the right margin.

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\section{Margin1}
\begin{itemize}
\item LONG sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line
\end{itemize}

\section{Section}
\textbf{Text \hfill YYYY}
SENTENCE

\section{Margin2}
\begin{itemize}
\item LONG sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to do such a thing without manually setting the margins for each section. If yes, how do I do it? If no, how do I prevent LaTeX from shifting the text away from the left margin?

Similarly, is there a  method of approach for the left hand margin? In particular, I would like to line up `SENTENCE` with the start of the itemization (where `LONG` starts).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Will the width of `YYYY` be same or different. Use `enumitem` and set proper `rightmargin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first requirement, use

```
\setlist[itemize]{rightmargin=\widthof{\textbf{YYYY}}}
```

for a global adjustment of `itemize` or, locally, use

```
\begin{itemize}[rightmargin=\widthof{\textbf{YYYY}}]
```

The above requires the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc), which provides `\widthof{..}`. The second adjustment is obtained by setting a regular `itemize` with an empty `\item[]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{res}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/res
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{enumitem,calc}
% Global change to itemize
%\setlist[itemize]{rightmargin=\widthof{\textbf{YYYY}}}
\begin{document}

\section{Margin1}
\begin{itemize}
\item LONG sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line
\end{itemize}

\section{Section}
\textbf{Text \hfill YYYY}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] SENTENCE
\end{itemize}

\section{Margin2}
\begin{itemize}[rightmargin=\widthof{\textbf{YYYY}}]
\item LONG sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line Long sentence that goes to the next line
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, though it has the unfortunate effect of causing the spacing between each word to be too large. Is there a package to fix this?

Comment: @Anonymous: You'll have to explain a little more. You could, of course, set the vertical spacing between itemized elements as well using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). See the `nosep` or `itemsep` options in the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: I was referring to the horizontal spacing between words, where changing the margins causes additional whitespace between words. Given even one or two long words, it looks aesthetically displeasing. Also, while the solution for 'SENTENCE' provides the desired results, it adds additional spacing if you have `SENTENCE` followed in the next line by `SENTENCE`. While  `\setlength{\itemsep}{-xpt}` seems to provide a manual result, how can I tell if the space between the two `SENTENCE` would be the same as if there were no `\itemize`?

Comment: @Anonymous: Horizontal space between words are necessarily flexible. You can change that, although that would make the output look weird. Perhaps using `\raggedright` might help. You'd have to look at the construction of an item in the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (section **3.2 Horizontal spacing of labels**, p 4 onward; section **3.3 More on horizontal spacing** also has some points on the label construction, yielding the horizontal lengths involved).